# Yii2 refresh facebook access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, yii2

I am using next code to post to user wall in yii2

```
        $client = Yii::$app->get('authClientCollection')->getClient('facebook');    
        $access_token  = new Facebook();
        $access_token->clientId = $client->clientId;
        $access_token->clientSecret = $client->clientSecret;
   $session = new FacebookSession($access_token->accessToken);
   if ($session) {
       try {
           $response = (new FacebookRequest(
                   $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
               'link' => 'test link',
               'message' => 'message here'
                   )
                   ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

           echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');
       } catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
           echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
           echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
       }
   }
```

but the problem I faced that I didn't find any way to extend access-token and refresh it using 'yii2 auth client class' or 'facebook sdk' , any idea please .

Comment: use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use yii\authclient\clients\Facebook;

Comment: did u find an answer ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if FacebookSession not found please look [sdk from v4 to v5](https://www.sammyk.me/upgrading-the-facebook-php-sdk-from-v4-to-v5)